# Flutter url_launcher not working MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to launch google map when tap on button, nothing complicated. i found easy code also from google search. Pasting the code below for reference. i dont know it is the proper way to do.

```
  class MapUtils {
    MapUtils._();

    static Future<void> openMap(double latitude, double longitude) async {
      String googleUrl =
          'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
      if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
        await launch(googleUrl);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not open the map.';
      }
    }
  }
```

pubspec.yaml added ->  url_launcher: ^6.0.17

i called this -> MapUtils.openMap(-33.2445107, 9.1530103)

Whenever i tap on the button return error as `"Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)"`

i tried to find solution, what i tried is
`Flutter clean`, `flutter pub get.`
Close everything reopen
uninstall app from emulator device.
close emulator and restart.
total computer restart.
it is nothing related url_launcher still i add the google map api to androidmanifest and appdelegate. Enables Api.
Lot of popel are asking about the same error. May be i am missing something todo.

Comment: Try with Uninstall app and run again, hope you run app without error.

Comment: @NehilKoshiya i did that too.  No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins. May be there is new way to open?

Comment: Have you tried launching any other url? Like normal url and not google maps.

Comment: @Pranav if i use chrome or any browser yes it is opening the google map site.

Comment: @NAJEEB I meant if the url launcher was working with something other than maps. Like is it able to open google.com from your app. This might help us to know if the problem is related to url launcher or something else.

Comment: same , cant open normal url too. but here also i can open url if choose the chrome as laucher(not android device)